# adding multiple subviews in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to add multiple subview programmatically, but my buttons inside those subviews are not working. The buttons were also added as subviews programmatically.

Here's the code, hopefully will explain more about what I mean.

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}

[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

// UIView container of selected image with comment button.
UIView *containerOfSelectedImage = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 0, 350)];

NSLog(@"%f", self.frame.size.width);
// image view of selected photo by user.
UIImageView *userImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nature_01.jpg"]];
[userImage setFrame :CGRectMake(0, 0, 340, 300)];

// comment button with action of recodering user's comment.
UIButton *commentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
//[commentButton setBackgroundColor : [UIColor clearColor]];
float y = userImage.frame.size.height + 5.0f;
[commentButton setFrame : CGRectMake(32.0f, y, 24.0f, 24.0f)];
[commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(audioRecordAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[commentButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"comments-24.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


[containerOfSelectedImage addSubview:userImage];
[containerOfSelectedImage addSubview:commentButton];

[self addSubview:containerOfSelectedImage];
[self addSubView:self.commentContainerView];
return self;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increase the frame of the `containerOfSelectedImage`. Currently the width is 0.

The containerOfSelectedImage's frame has to be big enough so the button fits inside it. If the button is outside that frame it will show up but you can't touch him.

To debug this issues you can use a tool like [Reveal App](http://revealapp.com/). If any of your buttons is outside the frame of the parent then the touch will not be detected.

Comment: thanks a lot mate, you just saved me a lot of time, that i've already waste at the past 3 hours.
problem solved.

Comment: No problem :). It is easier when someone already has been there. Please mark it as accepted as soon as you can so others can also save their time.

Answer (score 0):

Change `[commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(audioRecordAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];` to `[commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(audioRecordAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: Ok, perhaps `UIButton *commentButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];` return to you a different button, change for `UIButton *commentButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(32.0f, y, 24.0f, 24.0f)];`

Comment: thanks for you time mate, problem solved with writing the width of the UIView.

Comment: Yes, I don't see that line xD but, other lines are equal significant.